# Gradient descent using Newtons method

Tags: regression, python, optimization, gradient-descent

I am implementing gradient descent for regression using newtons method as explained in the 8.3 section of the Machine Learning A Probabilistic Perspective (Murphy) book. I am working with two dimensional data in this implementation. I am using following notations.
x =  input data points m*2
y =  labelled outputs(m) corresponding to input data
H = Hessian matrix  is defined as $$2*X^t X / m  $$

gradient descent update  $$ \theta = \theta - H^{-1}g(\theta) $$
where $ g(\theta) = 2* \sum_n (\theta^t x_{n} - y_{n})x $ is loss function.
In my case $\theta$ theta is $2*1$ array and  $H$ $2*2$ matrix.
Now my question is how to calculate $\theta$ as $H^{-1}$ is matrix of $2*2 $ the product will of loss function and $H^{-1}$ will be $2*2$ but theta is $2*1$. Here is my python implementation of it with work around considering only diagonal values of $H$. However this is not working as cost is increasing in each iteration.

```
def loss(x,y,theta):
   m,n = np.shape(x)
   predicted = np.dot(x, theta)    
   error = predicted - y
   cost = np.sum(error ** 2) / m
   return cost

def NewtonMethod(x,y,theta,maxIterations):
   m,n = np.shape(x)
   xTrans  = x.transpose()
   H       = 2 * np.dot(xTrans,x) / m
   Hinv    = np.linalg.inv(H)
   thetaPrev = np.zeros_like(theta)
   best_iter = maxIterations
   for i in range(0,maxIterations):
     cost = loss(x,y,theta)
     theta  = theta - np.diagonal(np.multiply(Hinv,cost))
     if np.array_equal(theta,thetaPrev):
        break;
     else:
       thetaPrev = theta
       best_iter = i
   return theta
```

Here are the sample values I used

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([[-1.7, -1.5],[-1.0 , -0.3],[ 1.7 ,  1.5],[-1.2, -0.7 ][ 0.6,  0.1]])  
y = np.array([ 0.3 ,  0.07, -0.2,  0.07,  0.03 ])
theta = np.zeros(2)
NewtonMethod(x,y,theta,100)
```

Need help / suggestions to fix this problem.

Comment: I will address only one point, and not the correctness or goodness of anything else you have done.  $g(\theta)$ should be the 2 by 1 gradient vector of the objective (i.e., loss) function.  You will therefore have a (2 by 2) matrix by (2 by 1) vector multiplication, which results in a 2 by 1 vector.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone : How loss function can be 2*1 vector. Can you explain?

Comment: The loss function is a scalar. The gradient of the loss function is 2 by 1, comprised of one component for reach dimension (variable).  The Hessian of the loss function is 2 by 2.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone : Thanks I made changes as suggested. But still cost is increasing in each iteration. Wondering whats going wrong